# Define strategy to social networks targeting multiple countries

Tags: small-communities, communication, social-network

I have a website about reviews targeting two countries, speaking the same language: *wwww.br.xxx.com* and *wwww.pt.xxx.com*.

Each review will only be relevant to the readers of that respective country (Brazilian reviews to Brazilian readers, Portuguese reviews to Portuguese readers).

My question is about the social profiles. When a new review is posted, my site shares the review automatically to Facebook, Twitter and Linked.

Should I have two profiles for each social medium, one for each site?

The problem is about the traction. One global profile will be much more easy to scale. Should I aggregate all reviews in a global profile?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why are the reasons for establishing two subdomains for your localized target groups invalid for establishing two social media sites / accounts? Or: What reasons spoke to you to establish two subdomains, yet not two social media sites / accounts even though you localize the community?

Comment: @Zerotime Even some big companies choose a global profiles, to avoid social fragmentation. If I create one account for each media I will have 2 linkedin, 2 Facebook and 2 twitter accounts. We are talking about 6 different platforms. Also, 6 new profiles without any relevant traction. In terms of community building this is just terrible.

Answer (score 3):

I think multiple profiles may be best. Would the PT or BR user be annoyed if they see (or if they are notified) of a new review for something that has nothing to do with them? Too much irrelevant content, on any medium, can cause you to lose followers.

Comment: I agree, but fragment a fragile and small identity doesn't seems good too.

Comment: You need to check that the terms of use of the social media sites allow non-personal and multiple accounts.